# Excel sum of each item from different sheets to its own sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I need to get the sum of each item from different worksheet to sheet D. For example I have in:

SHEET A:   SWEATER (A2) 500 (B2), BOOTS (A3) 200 (B3)
SHEET B:   BOOTS 100, CUP 50
SHEET C:   SWEATER 300, CUP 400

Comment: [Okay.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking of converting it to multiple tables then create a pivot table. Also, someone gave me this but I'm not sure if it will sum it up correctly: =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetNames!$A$2:$A$5&"'!$A$2:A11"),A2,INDIRECT("'"&SheetNames!$A$2:$A$5&"'!$B$2:B11")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the list is dynamic (ie adding jackets), you can look at using a pivot table with multiple ranges.

if it's not dynamic, you can use the sumif command with a formula for each sheet

=SUMIF(Sheet1!a:a,b1,Sheet1!b:b)+... where b1="SWEATER"

Comment: Thank you for validating my idea. It is dynamic so going with the pivot table is the best solution.